# Saving object into a list and modifying a string for the object without modifying entry in the list?

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist, reset

I'm trying to pass an object into a list. The object has a String attribute called "moves". After I've passed the object into the ArrayList I'd like to modify the object to reset the value of "moves" to it's original state without altering the object that has been passed to the list. How do I do this?

I'm really struggling please help.

Thank you

My code is:

```
           if(B[i] && B[j] && !B[k]){
                B[i]=!B[i];
                B[j]=!B[j];
                B[k]=!B[k];
                String previousMoves=board.moves;
                board.moves=board.moves+(i+"W"+k+", ");
                board.store(B);
                list.add(board);
                board.moves=previousMoves;//Resetting string back to original
                i++;j++;k++;
                B=Arrays.copyOf(H, 33);
            //Checks for a BWW situation
            //Makes switch to WBB
            }
```

Comment: You can't without making a copy of the original object.

Comment: To store 2 states, you obviously need 2 objects

Comment: @AliShobeiri, there's no shortcut. Just construct a new object and copy all the fields from the original.

Comment: Hey guys! 

Thank you so much, it worked perfectly by making a clone method!

I'm very new with objects so all your help was really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a copy of the object.  So, you could implement a method like `clone()` or a constructor which takes an object of the same type as argument.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!